# How to verify the correctness of the integration of 30 tables into one table on SQL server 2008 R2 on win7?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7

I have 30 tables , the column "ID" value is unique. I can set it as primary key. Each table has 100,000 rows.

```
ID        value 
397     3209166.899725
```

How to verify that all rows are integrated into the table without any one left ?

```
  each small table 
          Left join  big table
```

Check the null rows ?

Or

```
  SELECT a.* FROM small_table
  where not exists
  (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Big_table
    Where ID = small_table.ID
  )
```

Are there better ways ?

Thanks

Comment: Both your methods are very reasonable.  What do you mean by "better"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the EXCEPT set operator:

```
select id from small_table
except
select id from big_table
```